# I installed the python3.3.2 in my PC, ubuntu12.04. And the eric IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, ubuntu-12.04, eric-ide

For that the ubuntu itself installed the python2.7.3.
So after I set up the eric, the default IDE is stil python 2.7.3.
But I have installed python 3.3.2.
How to re-set this for eric? because I want to use the python 3.3.2.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/ it appears that:

- eric 4 is targeting python2
- eric 5 is targeting python3

And then looking at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=eric you'll see that eric, as packaged for Ubuntu, is only version 4 - meaning you've got one choice if you want to use eric right now:

- Compile eric 5 from source so you can do some python 3 programming, or
- Stay with eric 4 and python 2, if you feel more comfortable with precompiled packages.